Why was this answerable and answered question closed for lack of detail and clarity?
Jerry asked a question on June 5, and it was posted after being approved in the First Question queue.  It received an answer that same day, and to my eyes the question and answer are both good.
The question closed the next day with the reason "This question needs details or clarity."  That "details or clarity" link takes you to the Closed Questions page of the help center which really doesn't have much to say.

Sometimes we need more information in order to help solve your
problem.
This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and
be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the
comments.

Not exactly actionable advice on a question that already describes a plant species, a problem with it, some context, and a good answer.
The only comment at time of closure was asking for a photograph, from the user who was still able to write a good answer and did not vote to close.  I can't imagine this question was closed for lack of a picture, I must be missing something.  And if a cool cat like me misses it, how can we expect new users to catch it?
Why was this question closed, and how on Earth could Jerry know that?

I approve a lot questions from new users but that doesn't mean the question provides enough details to receive a good answer.  As we want to encourage new questions if there are some details and a clear question I will approve it and upvote it even if I don't think a good answer can be provided.
In this case a speculative answer was provided but without a picture a complete answer cannot be provided.  My experience is that if a user gets some feedback like an upvote and a request for more detail but does not provide more details within 24 hours then they are not coming back.
Feedback in the form of comments and upvotes can be received by a user by email if they enable that in their profile or by returning to the site where new interactions are highlighted in the top right corner.
